# How to add a confirmation dialog box depending on user input after ASP.NET validation has been performed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have got a jquery dialog box shown when ASP.NET validation fails, this is working fine. 
I need to add a confirmation dialog depending on the user input after the validation has been done and is succesful.

I added the dialog box, which comes up fine as expected but it doesn't wait for the user input and performs the server side process when I am expecting the user to decide to go on with the server side process or not

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {

     if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
         $("#validation_dialog").dialog({
             title: "¡No pudimos publicar!",
             modal: true,
             resizable: false,
             buttons: {
                 Close: function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                 }
             }
         });
         return false;
     }
     else
     {
         if ($("#<%=hClientePrivado.ClientID %>").val() === 'G') {
             if ($("#<%=hRubroGratis.ClientID %>").val() !== '0' || $("#<%=hoptTipo.ClientID %>").val() !== '0' || $("#<%=hWeb.ClientID %>").val() !== '0') {
                 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                     resizable: false,
                     title: "¡Favor confirmar!",
                     modal: true,
                     buttons: {
                         Yes: {
                             text: 'Si quiero publicar',
                             click: function () {
                                 return true;
                             }
                         },
                         No: {
                             text: 'No quiero publicar',
                             click: function () {
                                 return false;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
             else { return true;}
         }
         else { return true;}
     }
    }
```

I am expecting to display the #dialog-confirm dialog and wait until the user chooses Yes or No; if yes then to proceed with the server process and if no just close the dialog and coming back to the form

As requested in a comment, this code is triggered by the ASP.NET validation used as shown below

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPublicar"   ValidationGroup="grp1"   style="display:none;" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server" Text="Publicar" cssclass="btnPublicar"/><br />
 <div id="cldisabled" style="display:inline-block;color:#ff0000">
 <br />JavaScript está deshabilitado en su navegador web. Favor habilitarlo para poder publicar<br /><br />
  </div>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("btnPublicar").style.display = 'inline-block';
  document.getElementById("cldisabled").style.display = 'none';
  </script>
  <div id="validation_dialog" style="display: none">
  <asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="grp1"  ID="ValidationSummary1" 
   runat="server" />
   </div>
   <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
   <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ></span>Este aviso no es gratis 
   favor confirmar. ¿ Porque ? Seguramente por el rubro o por haber 
   escogido destacado o agregado una pagina web</p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: How and when are you calling `WebForm_OnSubmit`?

Comment: This is triggered by ASP.NET validation (see https://www.cnblogs.com/joeliu/archive/2008/05/28/1209563.html )

Comment: For the time being I changed my jquery dialog-confirm with a Javascript confirm which does the trick. Not as nice as the jQuery Dialog box but it does the job.